# Why is the option "link a device" required in Clash of Clans

Tags: clash-of-clans, android

I know that I can load my village on any device just by logging in to my gmail account which is associated with my village. So what does the "link a device" option do and why is it needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "link a device" option enables you to play your village on multiple devices but importantly with different operating systems. For example an Apple iOS device and an Android device. Without the "link a device" option cross platform accounts would not be possible.

[Here is a good Guide in the wiki on linking devices](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Device_Linking_Guide)